# How to silence "New names" message from `map_dfc()`?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Supose, I have a function that returns a `data.frame`, like this one:

```
foo<-function(sd){
  data.frame(
    first=rnorm(2,0,sd),
    second=rnorm(2,0,sd/2)
  )
}
```

Now, when I use `purrr:map_dfc()` to create single `data.frame` from `data.frame`s produced by `foo`, I get:

```
map_dfc(1:2, foo)

New names:
* first -> first...1
* second -> second...2
* first -> first...3
* second -> second...4
  first...1 second...2 first...3 second...4
1 0,6905908  0,1499820 -0,685636  1,0323695
2 1,7293986 -0,4653913 -2,049278 -0,2364952
```

Which is fine, but is there a way to silence "New names" message that apears in console?

**EDIT**
I am aware of `suppressMessages()` but it silences all possible messages, while I wish to silnece **only** "New names" message.

Comment: `suppressMessages(map_dfc(1:2, foo))`

Comment: I forgot, about `suppressMessages`. I mean is there a way to silence only "New names" message, not all possible messages. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove the reason why you get those messages at first place.

```
foo <- function(sd, name){
  tibble::tibble(
    'first_{{name}}' := rnorm(2,0,sd),
    'second_{{name}}' := rnorm(2,0,sd/2)
  )
}

purrr::imap_dfc(1:2, foo)

#  first_1L second_1L first_2L second_2L
#     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1    0.683    -1.25    -2.03      0.801
#2   -1.17      0.530   -0.170    -0.148
```